# PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider UserDetailsService how to catch the right exception

Tags: spring-security, exception, pre-authentication

I am under Spring Boot 2.0.5 (Spring Security 5.0.8)

I have setup a preauthentication filter chain, which works fine, only thing problematic is the exception handling, especially those thrown form my custom UserDetailsService. I also tried to return a User with "enabled = false" but still the same.

See code below for my custom UserDetailsService:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class PreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService
        implements AuthenticationUserDetailsService<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> {

    @Autowired
    private AccessService accessService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserDetails(PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {

        String accessId = token.getCredentials() + "";

        try {
            AccessEntity accessEntity = accessService.getAccessByAccessId(accessId);

            if (accessEntity == null) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException(String.format("Unknown access (AccessId=%s)", accessId));
            }

            List<AccessRole> accessRoles = accessEntity.getRoles();

            if (!accessEntity.getActive()) {                    
                return new User(accessEntity.getUid(), accessEntity.getUid(), false, true, true, true, accessRoles.stream()
                        .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toList()));
                //throw new AccessDeniedException(String.format("Inactive access (AccessId=%s)", accessId));
            }

            return new User(accessEntity.getUid(), accessEntity.getUid(), accessRoles.stream()
                    .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception in load user details", e);
            throw new BadCredentialsException(String.format("Authentication issue for accessId=%s", accessId));
        }
    }

}
```

And my Security Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String SPRING_ROLE_ANONYMOUS = "ANONYMOUS"; // ("ROLE_" is automatically inserted as prefix)

    @Autowired
    private AppConfigProperties appConfigProperties;

    @Autowired
    RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    RESTAccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

    @Autowired
    PreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(preauthAuthProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preauthAuthProvider() {
        PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preauthAuthProvider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
        preauthAuthProvider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService);
        return preauthAuthProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter filter = new RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setPrincipalRequestHeader(appConfigProperties.getSecurity().getRequestHeaderTokenKeyName());
        filter.setCredentialsRequestHeader(appConfigProperties.getSecurity().getRequestHeaderTokenKeyName());
        filter.setExceptionIfHeaderMissing(false);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        return filter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        RequestMatcher protected_urls = new OrRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher(
                appConfigProperties.getSecurity().getProtectedUrls()));
        http
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
            .addFilterBefore(requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST , appConfigProperties.getSecurity().getUserAuthenticatePath())
                .hasRole(SPRING_ROLE_ANONYMOUS)
            .requestMatchers(protected_urls).authenticated()
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
                .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .logout().disable(); // disable autoconfig
    }

    /**
     * Disable Spring boot automatic filter registration.
     */
    @Bean
    FilterRegistrationBean<RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter> disableAutoRegistration(final RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter filter) {
        final FilterRegistrationBean<RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(filter);
        registration.setEnabled(false);
        return registration;
    }
}

@Component
@Slf4j
public class RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Autowired
    private AppConfigProperties appConfigProperties;

    @Override
    public void commence(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
            final AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {

        log.error("********* Authentication Entry Point exception", authException);

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        String responseContentJson = null;

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        responseContentJson = new Gson().toJson(GlobalExceptionHandler.createSWError(SWErrorCode.HTTP,
                String.format("Failed authentication: missing request header '%s' or invalid value",
                        appConfigProperties.getSecurity().getRequestHeaderTokenKeyName())));

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print(responseContentJson);
        out.flush();
        response.flushBuffer();
    }

}
```

I also tried to use an "accessDeniedHandler" but it never goes through it.

The issue is that for any exception thrown (either in my custom UserDetailsService or others), it goes through my custom "AuthenticationEntryPoint" with an always similar exception, see below:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full authentication is required to access this resource
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleSpringSecurityException(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:190)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:141)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any idea would be great!